# Proof that limit exists in $L^2$ sence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Proof that exists $L^2$ limit
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0} L(t,\varepsilon)=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_0^t\mathbf{1}\left(W_s\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\right)ds,
$$
where $W_s$ is a Brownion motion and $\varepsilon>0$ and $t$ is a fixed number.

I really don't know how to proof this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know anything about local times?

Comment: No, this is the only thing that I know. :/